# Why the manage.py file is not executed in the App Engine Flexible dockerfile?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

So the dockerfile that App Engine uses to generate a container for a Django app is as following:

```html
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python@sha256:c6480acd38ca4605e0b83f5196ab6fe8a8b59a0288a7b8216c42dbc45b5de8f6

LABEL python_version=python3.7

RUN virtualenv --no-download /env -p python3.7

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env

ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

ADD requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app/

CMD exec gunicorn -b :$PORT myteam.wsgi
```

My question is then why don't we see the command :

`python manage.py runserver`

And instead we see :  `gunicorn -b :$PORT myteam.wsgi`

Does it imply that the *gunicorn* command runs the server ?

Comment: Do you have the documentation showing that specific Dockerfile? You can see [this summary](https://serverfault.com/questions/331256) about the reasoning behind using gunicorn to be your web server. You can also check this documentation dealing with using [Gunicorn with Django](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#django).

Comment: Yes, you can find the documentation here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime

Comment: Thanks for sharing. From my understanding, gunicorn is needed to handle requests that need to be dynamically generated, in other words that interact with the python code. So rather than running : "python manage.py runserver", gunicorn runs "application = get_wsgi_application()" and I believe it is responsible for running the code.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine deployments often handle heavy traffic from users across the world. When you run [`python manage.py runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server) in a django application, you are serving the application on the local machine for development purposes.

In theory you could use this as the container command in your App Engine app, but this is not its intended purpose and [never recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server):

> Now’s a good time to note: don’t use this server in anything resembling a production environment. It’s intended only for use while developing...

App Engine deployments demand a more robust web server software, and for Python applications that would involve using a [WSGI](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html) server (such as Gunicorn) to serve the application.

Since Django can be easily integrated with Gunicorn, all you need is the command you see in the App Engine sample Dockerfile.